# Angular 2: Cannot find module 'angular2/core'

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, gulp, gulp-typescript

I'm having a problem with Angular 2 + Typescript, whenever I try to gulp build it shows me the same errors, I have tried everything including putting the <reference> tags in the files. What to do?

> ```
> (7,26): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs/Rx'./Users/macbook/workspace/rss/src/app/services/rootscope.ts
> (8,46): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'angular2/core'./Users/macbook/workspace/rss/src/app/services/rootscope.ts
> (17,48): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Observer'./Users/macbook/workspace/rss/src/app/services/api.ts
> (6,26): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'angular2/core'./Users/macbook/workspace/rss/src/app/services/api.ts
> (7,27): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'angular2/http'./Users/macbook/workspace/rss/src/app/services/api.ts
> (15,13): error TS2339: Property 'http' does not exist on type 'API'./Users/macbook/workspace/rss/src/app/services/api.ts
> (19,20): error TS2339: Property 'http' does not exist on type 'API'./Users/macbook/workspace/rss/src/app/services/api.ts
> (23,20): error TS2339: Property 'http' does not exist on type 'API'../src/app/app.ts
> (6,25): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'angular2/platform/browser'../src/app/app.ts
> (7,25): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'angular2/core'../src/app/app.ts
> (8,47): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'angular2/http'.
> ```

**rootscope.ts**

```
/// <reference path="../../../node_modules/reflect-metadata/reflect- metadata.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../../../node_modules/angular2/typings/browser.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../../../node_modules/angular2/core.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../../../node_modules/angular2/http.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../../../node_modules/rxjs/Rx.d.ts" />

import {Observable} from "rxjs/Rx";

import {Injectable,EventEmitter,Output} from "angular2/core";

@Injectable()
export class ROOT_SCOPE {
  data: any;
  dataChange: Observable<any>;
  @Output dataChangeObserver: EventEmitter=new EventEmitter();

  constructor() {
    this.dataChange = new Observable((observer:Observer) => {
      this.dataChangeObserver = observer;
    });
  }

  set(data:any) {
    this.data = data;
    this.dataChangeObserver.next(this.data);
  }
}
```

Comment: What Angular2 version are you using? For => RC.x you need `@angular/...` instead of `angular2/...`

Comment: Which version of angular2 are you dealing with?

Comment: after releasing `beta` `last - beta.17` versions, now `Release Candidate` `current - RC.4` version is going. Requesting you to update yourself.

Comment: I have updated to 2.0.0-beta.17, still having the same problem.

Comment: Guys, please help I have a deadline.

Comment: Any reason you don't use `RC.4? Use angular-cli to setup the project https://cli.angular.io/

Comment: I used RC.4 and it's working great, thank you mate.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue before because of System.config.js misconfiguration.
Try to check if the configuration is correct.

Comment: In my case I think it was the base path of the application. Sorry, I don't remember very well.

Answer (score -1):

**Configure External Web tools**

Configure Visual Studio to use the global external web tools instead of the tools that ship with Visual Studio:

•Open the Options dialog with Tools | Options

•In the tree on the left, select Projects and Solutions | External Web Tools.

•On the right, move the $(PATH) entry above the $(DevEnvDir) entries. This tells Visual Studio to use the external tools (such as npm) found in the global path before using its own version of the external tools.

•Click OK to close the dialog.

•Restart Visual Studio for this change to take effect.

Comment: Where does OP even says he use Visual studio?